# Why the '@' in the comments?

Tags: php

Sometimes I see php comments with '@' in front of some lines. Like `@Author`. Is there any particular reason for this? I cannot seem to find anything about this. I am assuming there is highly used parser that looks for '@'s.

Comment: google: "php documenter"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is most likely [phpDocumentor](http://www.phpdoc.org/) notation, a program which parses source code (and those @ comments) to auto-generate documentation. Many IDEs also provide intelligent lookup and autocomplete functionality based on these comments.

Example:

```
/**
 * Echoes "example".
 * @author Pekka
 * @version 1.5
 * @return void
 */
 function example()
  {
   echo "example";
  }
```

Comment: Funny how I could've forgotten when I just provided a phpDocumentor-related answer last week. +1

Comment: I know you know this, just think that it will be useful to add to the answer that phpdoc comments also used by IDEs in autocomplete.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I figured that's what it was, now I know the program. I never thought to google "Documenter". Makes sense.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't realize what they were either till I started using netbeans.

Answer (score 2):

This is used by automatic documentation generators to create documentation from the comments.  There are a few tools and formats out there:

- phpDocumentor
- Doxygen
- HeaderDoc

To list a few.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of packages that parse source code for comments and create intricate help files in various formats (like HTML, Windows .chm files, etc.). Java, obviously, has javadoc, but there's also [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) and [Doc-O-Matic](http://www.doc-o-matic.com/), just to name a few.